# How to print the output in an output.txt and listed per line

Tags: python

I have a code which prints all the 6 string combination from ascii_lowercase.

Here is the code:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 2)]

print(keywords)
```

The output is like this.

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad',...'zx', 'zy', 'zz']
```

Printing it like this took up all the space in command prompt. How can I print this to an output.txt file with 2 strings per line list instead?

For example,instead of

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad',...'zx', 'zy', 'zz']
```

I want the output as this in an output.txt file

```
aa
ab
ac
...
zy
zz
```

Comment: you can't print to a file, but you can write to a file: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop over the list and print each item rather than printing the list itself

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k in ''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 2):
        f.write('{}\n', k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 2)]

for i in range(0,len(keywords),2):
    print(f'{keywords[i]} {keywords[i+1]}')
```

To write to file use:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for i in range(0,len(keywords),2):
        fp.write(f'{keywords[i]} {keywords[i+1]}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for string in keywords:
        file.write(string + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. If all you are going to do with that output is to write it line-by-line to a file, then you do not even need to generate the list in the first place:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2):
        f.write(''.join(i) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can `print` in the way you want, for example:

```
>>> some_list = [chr(i) for i in range(80,90)]
>>> some_list
['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y']
>>> f = open('somefile.txt', 'w')
>>> print(*some_list, sep='\n', file=f)
>>> f.close()
```

`somefile.txt`:

```
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
```

In your case it can be:

```
keywords = (''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 2))
with open('output.txt') as f:
    print(*keywords, sep='\n', file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a context manager:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    for i in product(ascii_lowercase, 2)
        f.write(''.join(i)+'\n')
```